# Running tensoflow inference graph in android

Tags: android, tensorflow, object-detection

I am new to app development.  I want to run my trained object detection model in android.  The model is produced by [Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md).  Hence the output is in frozen_inference_graph.pb format.

I have looked into the documentation [page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android/).  It gives multiple options.  I could not figure out which one is suitable for me.  Any suggestion on which path to choose among the following :

1. Building in Android Studio using the TensorFlow AAR from JCenter
2. Building the Demo with TensorFlow from Source

thanks and regards
skbhat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have pros and cons but either way could do the work.

1. get the prebuilt library (tensorflow_inference.so) with jni wrappers enables you to build your app with ease, so I think it's recommended way to begin.
2. Build from source takes some time and sometimes it's troublesome (depends on your current environment), but it gives you to highly customize/optimize overall functions. so I guess it' better if you have enough knowledge on manipulating core apis (like adding/removing ops, etc.)

To make it short, in my opinion, if you are new to android tensorflow, then take the libraries from JCenter would be more than enough.